# Accessing or passing Express Session Data to Angular 6

Tags: node.js, angular, express, session, nginx

In our setup, we are using Nginx, Node 8.11, and Angular CLI 6 and I'm trying to get the values set in Express back to the Angular 6 frontend.

I think I might have a unique setup and I need a little help with how to proceed. In our setup, we have a company required login page that all apps route to. When a user successfully logins into that page, it will redirect back to the calling site and then continue on with the normal processing.

The flow is like this;

**First:** 
A user enters our internal url - https://myawesome.company.com/myapp We use nginx and node. Then in our node server.js we set up a session in express like this:

```
// setup our session managment
var session = require('express-session');
app.use(session({
   name: config.ses_cookie_name,
   resave: true,
   saveUninitialized: true,
   secret: config.session_secret
}));
```

**Step 2:**
Our node server.js then calls a route/process - for example    *app.use(auth.verifyuser());* that calls the company login page and which in turn will validate users (or not) and send back the user info.

**Step 3.** 
Once the node app gets valid user info from the company login page it goes ahead and routes the user to the main angular app.

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
     res.sendFile(path.resolve('dist/index.html'));
    }
});
```

My main issue is - at this point I have the creds for the user (user name, level, etc) BEFORE I start the angular portion of the app. However, I can't figure out how to pass this information to the Angular app OR if angular already has access to these variables. Any advice would be appreciated.

Also, I'm no expert and have been learning as I go.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't send any data using the `res.sendFile(...)` method along with the html that you have there, Instead you can use the [`res.render`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) method like this,

```
res.render('index', { loggedInUser: loggedInUserObj }, function(err, html) {
  // ...
});
```

Note: In the above example assume that the `loggedInUserObj` is holding your logged in user's data.

In order to use this, you need to set your `view engine` like this,

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

And then you can define your `index` page (which you are rendering using the `res.render`) like this, here I'm dumping the `loggedInUserObj` object to ensure our data is getting passed.

```
 <%- JSON.stringify(loggedInUserObj) %>
```

Hope this helps!